Using a Process Builder on Mac
I am writing a simple programme in Java where a process builder will create a file on mac OS.
Below is my code
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("touch malicious.file");
    System.out.println("Malicious !!");
    pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    pb.start();

When I run this programe , I get below error -
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "touch malicious.file" (in directory "/Users/<myusername>"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more

Java Version I am using is below and using MacOS Sonoma
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

Is there anything I am missing here ?

You need to separate the program and the arguments. new ProcessBuilder("touch", "malicious.file")
